# How to embed a random YouTube video by fetching it only from a playlist and without being embedded the entire playlist

Tags: java

Dears,

With iFrame like below, a random video can be embedded. But it also embeds the entire playlist.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" loading="lazy" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=playlist&amp;list=PlayList_ID&index=5" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The same can be achieved in some other code snippets/ YT api even by a novice like me, but they all embed the entire playlist (3 lines at top-right on the player).

**Please come forward in building a standalone code snippet-** let's make it possible to embed a random video fetched from a playlist without being embedded the entire playlist.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to embed a random video from a playlist without the entire playlist (three lines at the top-right) with it. Such embedding snippets are available in links: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=embed+youtube+video+from+playlist

Comment: I find a GitHub link and the code does very close to what I wanted. But it usage index number in the code. Moreover, I am also expecting auto pause while playing other video on the same page. URL: https://github.com/juliafmorgado/auto-embed-youtube